# Detect HD and Install SPI drivers

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, macbook

I purchased a MacBook 12” 2016. I decided to triple boot it with Windows and Ubuntu, using [this tutorial](https://www.innoq.com/en/blog/triple-booting-a-mac/#introduction). I had no USB-C to USB converter, so I used a temporary partition.  After installing Boot Camp services, I used Rufus because Mac Linux USB Loader didn't detect the partition. `intremap=nosid` booted it, but the trackpad and keyboard didn’t work (missing SPI drivers).

I found [applespi](https://github.com/cb22/macbook12-spi-driver) too confusing, so I tried the whole thing again. The same thing happened, but this time, Mac Linux USB Loader detected my HD partition (definitely same format and everything). Using Mac Linux USB Loader, it said ‘missing live operating system’ (tried with Rufus again and the same thing happened).

I got a multiple USB converter to come. It booted from a Rufus USB and a mouse worked, but didn’t detect the HD. I reckon ‘missing live operating system’ was because it couldn’t detect my HD and the partition I trying to boot from was on it (so without error it would probably detect my HD booted from USB).

There is [a thread link](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=108331) where someone got the keyboard working which would be ok, but too confusing. [Another one](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=99891)

**What I am asking is, what happened to my HD? And how can I install [this driver](https://github.com/cb22/macbook12-spi-driver)?**

Thank You :)

Comment: @Zanna Thank you for editing.  Sorry, it was quite long and I struggled to shorten it.

Comment: No worries... I see why you felt the need to include the background, but short, sharply defined questions are better suited to the site's format. Hope you get an answer :/

Comment: @Zanna Ok, thank you.  I will remember that.  This is the first time I have ever asked a question publicly.  Is there any way to get people to see it?  Because I noticed you saw this quickly.

Comment: I saw it in review - community members with more than 500 reputation are responsible for checking first posts by new users, to help them learn to use the site, fix formatting, flag anything that shouldn't be here. I don't have access to any kind of Mac and HDDs aren't my area, but I'll see if I can make any sense of the instructions to install the driver when I have time

Comment: did you find a solution in the end?

Comment: @Zanna Sadly not :(  Im using ubuntu docked (keyboard, moniter, ethernet etc) at the moment but would still like these drivers so I can use it normally.  Do you know how to follow those threads?  Thank you, and sorry for the late reply.